# datepicker not working when its https

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I was creating a portal where it shows all the records of the company sales and services. I have used datatable to show the reports and datepicker to filter date range. but after installing the SSL Certificates the datepicker doesn't work but when I search with http:// then it works very nicely. What could be the problem ?

It will be very kind if you guide me with it. I am really stuck.

Thank You

Comment: Check that no JS is loaded using `http://` on the site. If the site is under `https://` and you're trying to load any assets and resources (JS, CSS, Images etc) using `http://`, most browsers will block those files as "unsafe". Check the browsers console.

Answer (score 0):

You have given your Bootstrap or jQuery a reference `http` path. Change your referrals that you receive from the outside of the server in `http` to the `https`

sample:

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
```

to

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: Thank you it really helped..

Comment: If helpful please confirm